# How to give execute permissions to an external hard drive

Tags: permissions, steam

I just bought a 1 TB My Passport external hard drive an I am trying to run steam games off of it. When I try to download games there it says the folder must be in a drive with execute permissions. I have searched other similar questions and cannot seem to find the right answer. Running ubuntu 14.10 if that matters.NTFS file system.

Comment: ntfs file system

Comment: if this is too complicated or your have questions do PM me :)

Comment: external disk is mounted at media/user/passport

Comment: named /dev/sdb1  and I am not sure what ntfs-3g is. Sorry for the noob questions.

Comment: that is our native ntfs driver; it is installed if memory serves me well (it is added to the kernel a while back). So don't worry about that one. Oh I removed that bit since I had fstab in there as an alternative method but the udev method does not require those (udev rule will work for all usb)

Comment: Okay so I have a couple more dumb questions for you. After I enter this sudo vi /etc/udev/90-usb-disks.rules I am having trouble figuring out how to add ENV{ID_FS_TYPE}=="ntfs", ENV{ID_FS_TYPE}="ntfs-3g" . After the first command A bunch of these "~ " showing up in the terminal and I am not sure what to do. Thank you for all the help so far!

Answer (score 0):

The command

```
lsblk -f
```

will list all the disks (even when not mounted). Check with that what filesystem the external disk is using if you are unsure.

If the disk is formatted with a NTFS the preferred method is to do this with a udev rule. Create a file in `/etc/udev/` (with sudo) and call it something like `90-usb-disks.rules` or `99-usb-disks.rules`. (ie. `sudo vi /etc/udev/90-usb-disks.rules`)

Put `ENV{ID_FS_TYPE}=="ntfs", ENV{ID_FS_TYPE}="ntfs-3g"` into it and save the file.

Unplug the USB, insert it again and it should auto-mount with the disk fully open. (automount sets permissions at  600 by default; this method makes it set it as 777).

There are more methods, like adding it to `/etc/fstab` but who wants to add a new line each time another USB disk is inserted?

Comment: Here's what I see for the lsblk -f command
sdb      8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0 931.5G  0 part /media/username/My Passport

I tried adding a rule file in /etc/udev/rules/90-usb-disks.rules, uplugged and plugged back in.  Now I can run the eclipse executable I put on the external HD!